# How to access (iterate?) an ArrayList/Hashmap in another class?

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, iteration, android-activity

I have defined an ArrayList in my main class where I am loading data from an XML feed and creating various tabs with different activities:

```
static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Example of where I put a map entry into the ArrayList of HashMaps:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {      
  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();  
  Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
  map.put("id", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "id"));
  map.put("lat", "Lat: " + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "lat"));
  map.put("long", "Long: " + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "long"));
  mylist.add(map);
}
```

The first tab is a ListViewActivity and I am successfully able to create the list by referencing the ArrayList in the main class: *class.mylist* via a List Adapter:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                      ListViewActivity.this,
                      main.mylist, R.layout.list,
                      new String[] { "id", "lat", "long" }, 
                      new int[] { R.id.item_id, R.id.item_lat, R.id.item_long });                   
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

My second tab is a MapView and I am able to successfully switch tabs, display the map within the tab layout and pan & zoom etc.

Where I need help is with understanding how to access the 'lat' and 'long' strings within the "mylist" ArrayList/Hashmap in the main class (**Note**: *I declared the ArrayList/Hashmap in the main class and then share it across all the activities because it is quite a large XML feed and I did not want to be reloading data or having too many objects in memory*).

My objective is to then convert these lat/long co-ordinates into GeoPoints and display them using a Map Overlay; I am already able to do this using fixed GeoPoints hard-coded into my Map activity class.  However, as I wrote above, I now need to replace these 'fixed' GeoPoints and instead use the contents of the "mylist" ArrayList/Hashmap.

I am new (<1 month experience) to programming Java/Android, so I hope this all makes sense?  And I hope that someone will be able to explain / give an example of how I can access the data... I've tried implementing various measures such as '**Iterations**', but it's not working yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a couple of things. You could have your feed be a static variable. If it was static, you could access it from any place by writing `MyActivity.myList`.

Also, you could pass the XML string via the intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityToLaunch.class);
i.putExtra("xml", xml);
startActivity(i);
```

And then retrieve it with:

```
String xml = getIntent().getExtras().getString("xml");
```

Another idea, if the file is really big, would be to save the xml file to the sd card and load it in each activity.

Having done on of these, you can iterate over the ArrayList like this

```
for(HashMap<String,String> map: myList)
```

and then iterate through each HashMap in a couple of ways:

```
for(String s: map.keyset())
```

which would allow you to get the value by the key, or you can iterate through the values directly like this:

```
for(String s: map.values())
```

Comment: Hi Joru, yes I had already declared the 'mylist' ArrayList as a static variable as you suggested - rather than passing it via an Intent.  With your suggestion above, I have now been able to successfully iterate through the ArrayList and display all the data in my hashmap objects in the Logcat.  However, having retrieved the values, I am still unclear how to access a specific entry such as id, lat or long?  (Sorry if my question is very basic, but as I explained I am very novice at this)

Comment: Looking at your code again, you might want to define a small class of some kind and use a list of that instead of using hashmap. A class that would have the members id, lat and long. http://kkrit.com/n/Java_1.6_Tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html this is an example of how to declare a class. To access lat, for example, as you have it now, you need to do map.get("lat");.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you were looking for a way to *iterate* over the `ArrayList`?  If so, this example should get you started:

```
Iterator itr = myList.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
  HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) itr.next();
  String lat = (String) map.get("lat");
  String lon = (String) map.get("long");
  String id = (String) map.get("id");
  Log.d(TAG, "Lat is: " +lat);
  Log.d(TAG, "Lon is: " +lon);
  Log.d(TAG, "ID is: " +id);
 }
```

Comment: Hi Marvin - that worked perfectly, thank you so much for the quick response!

Comment: it work perfectly,  But Little problem i have change in my code map.get(lat); ,map.get(long); map.get(id) then its work man ., i voted u thax